# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (when i pass an object as argument in my add function it through Uncaught SyntaxError)

Tags: javascript

In this code when i passing an object in my add function as argument it threw Uncaught SyntaxError:

```js
const searchResultsList = document.getElementById('searchResultsList');

function add(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}

function showResult() {
        const li = document.createElement('LI');
        const obj = { abc: "xyz" }        
        li.innerHTML = `<button onclick="add(${obj})">Favourites</button>`;
        searchResultsList.appendChild(li);        
}
showResult();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code, since you're using a string on `innerHTML`

1. you need to make a string out of your object with `JSON.stringify`,
2. you need to use single quotes on function.

This works:

```js
const searchResultsList = document.getElementById('searchResultsList');

function add(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}

function showResult() {
        const li = document.createElement('LI');
        const obj = {abc: "xyz"}        
        li.innerHTML = `<button onclick='add(${JSON.stringify(obj)})'>Favourites</button>`;
        searchResultsList.appendChild(li);        
}
showResult();
```

```html
<ul id='searchResultsList'>
</ul>
```

However, I'd suggest you using button element instead of string. Thus you don't need any extra magic and the code is more readable:

```js
const searchResultsList = document.getElementById('searchResultsList');

function add(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}

function showResult() {
        const li = document.createElement('LI');
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        const obj = { abc: "xyz" }        

        button.textContent = 'Favourites';
        button.addEventListener('click', () => add(obj));
        
        li.appendChild(button);
        searchResultsList.appendChild(li);        
}
showResult();
```

```html
<ul id="searchResultsList">
</ul>
```

In addition, to make it easier to re-use, I'd suggest adding object as data property:

```js
const searchResultsList = document.querySelector('#searchResultsList');

function add() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.dataset.obj));
}

function showResult() {
    const li = document.createElement('LI');
    const button = document.createElement('button');

    button.textContent = 'Favourites';
    button.dataset.obj = JSON.stringify({ abc: "xyz" });
    button.addEventListener('click', add);
        
    li.appendChild(button);
    searchResultsList.appendChild(li);        
}

showResult();
```

```html
<ul id='searchResultsList'>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in an object directly into a string, which will interpreted as `'[object Object]'`. One way to get around this is to build your `<button/>` (just like how you build your `<li/>`).

```js
const searchResultsList = document.getElementById('searchResultsList');

function add(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}

function showResult() {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const obj = {
    abc: "xyz"
  };
  // Create button 
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'Favourites';
  button.onclick = () => add(obj);
  // Add button to <li/>
  li.appendChild(button);
  // Add <li/> to searchResultsList
  searchResultsList.appendChild(li);
}
showResult();
```

```html
<ul id="searchResultsList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just solved the same problem and I realized the difference between " vs '.

Try to change your object

```
const obj = { abc: 'xyz' }
```

not

```
const obj = { abc: "xyz" }
```

Then you can send object as parameters.

Here is reason

In Javascript you cannot put double quotation in doubule quotation.

ex) " "aa" " => (x) / " 'aa' " => (o)

So look at this code which you wrote

```
li.innerHTML = `<button onclick="add(${obj})">Favourites</button>`;
```

onclikck = "" you use double quotation and your object defiend like this

```
const obj = { abc: "xyz" }
```

now you can see you use double quotation in double quotation.

It will be fixed if you change double quotation in single quotation.